# gatsby-source-shopify and graphql error an error occurred while sourcing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

My problem is that I would like to connect my Shopify store with gatsby app. So I had installed gatsby-source-shopify, but when I added plugin to `gatsby-config.js` with shopName and accessToken and try to run gatsby develop, site renders as expected but it throws this error:

```
gatsby-source-shopify/gatsby-ecommerce-testing starting to fetch data from Shopify

 ERROR 


error an error occurred while sourcing data


 ERROR 

query: 
  """

      query GetCollections($first: Int!, $after: String) {
        collections(first: $first, after: $after) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
          }
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              description
              descriptionHtml
              handle
              id
              image {
                altText
                id
                src
              }
              products(first: 250) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                  }
                }
              }
              title
              updatedAt
            }
          }
        }
      }

  """
variables: 
  first: 250
  after: null
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. I think it may be something specific to the store or the (high) number of products, because when I try with a fake store with 1 product, it works fine.

Comment: I think this issue is because I didn't intall graphql plugin in gatsby app, but I'll check if this is true

Comment: How many products do you have? Have you taken a look at the gatsby starter file?
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/AlexanderProd/gatsby-shopify-starter/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it by coping the "Storefront access token" under storefront api permissions and not the "API token".

Comment: But where did you paste it?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `shopify-buy` package.